# Ordering relation between two sets of generalized eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider $A,B,C\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, where $A,B,C$ are each symmetric, $B,C$ are positive definite and $A$ is positive semidefinite. Furthermore $x^{\top}Bx\geq x^{\top}Cx$. Let $u_{k}$, $\lambda_{k}$ be the generalized eigenvectors and eigenvalues of

\begin{align*}
Au_{k}=\lambda_{k}Bu_{k},\quad k=1,2,\dots,N
\end{align*}

also $v_{k},\mu_{k}$ are the generalized eigenvectors and eigenvalues of

\begin{align*}
Av_{k}=\mu_{k}Cv_{k}, k=1,2,\dots,N
\end{align*}

furthermore these eigenvalues, that are known to be positive and real, are ordered in descending order, $\lambda_{1}\geq \lambda_{2}\geq\dots\geq\lambda_{N}$ and $\mu_{1}\geq \mu_{2}\geq\dots\geq \mu_{N}$.

It can be shown that $\mu_{1}\geq \lambda_{1}$ as

\begin{align*}
\lambda_{1}=
\frac{v_{1}^{\top}Av_{1}}{v_{1}^{\top}Bv_{1}}\leq\frac{v_{1}^{\top}Av_{1}}{v_{1}^{\top}Cv_{1}}
\leq \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{N}}\frac{x^{\top}Ax}{x^{\top}Cx}=\mu_{1}
\end{align*}

$\textbf{I'd like to show that}$ $\mu_{k}\geq \lambda_{k}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,N$, though I am not sure that this is true.

Progress that I have made. I have been able to show that for any $x\in$Span$\lbrace u_{j}\rbrace_{j=1}^{k}$ that

\begin{align*}
x^{\top}Ax\geq \lambda_{k}x^{\top}Bx\geq \lambda_{k}x^{\top}Cx
\end{align*}

which further allows me to conclude that

\begin{align*}
\inf_{x\in \text{Span}\lbrace u_{j}\rbrace_{j=1}^{k}}\frac{x^{\top}Ax}{x^{\top}Cx}\geq \lambda_{k}
\end{align*}

what I would like to be able to say is that given that for all vectors $x$ that are in the $k$-dimensional subspace Span$\lbrace u_{j}\rbrace_{j=1}^{k}$, the Rayleigh quotient $x^{\top}Ax/(x^{\top}Cx)\geq \lambda_{k}$ that there must then be $k$ generalized eigenvalues $\mu_{1},\dots,\mu_{k}$ such that $\mu_{j}\geq \lambda_{k}$ for $1\leq j\leq k$ but I am not sure that that is true.